# Error in custom ControlTemplate in TextBox

Tags: wpf, style, textbox

Почему курсор скрывается за TextBox?

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="Black"/>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Почему курсор скрывается за TextBox?

потому что он такого же цвета, что и фон. Измените цвет курсора и его станет видно:

```
<TextBox CaretBrush="White" ...
```